# How to hide layer when click outside in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I have toggle button that it show/hide layer.

Lets say the layer width is 300px, height is 300px.

How to hide the layer  when click outside area of layer?

This is code that I have so far below.

```
const Navi = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [show2, setShow2] = useState(false);

  const onToggleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
    setShow2(false);
  };

  const onToggleClick2 = () => {
    setShow(false);
    setShow2(!show2);
  };

  const resetToggle = () => {
    setShow(false);
    setShow2(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrap-navi">
      <div className="navi">
        <NavLink to="/menu" onClick={resetToggle}>
          menu
        </NavLink>
        <button onClick={onToggleClick} className={show ? "active" : ""}>
          toggle1
        </button>
        <button onClick={onToggleClick2} className={show2 ? "active" : ""}>
          toggle2
        </button>
      </div>
      <nav className={`layer1 ${show ? "active" : ""}`}>toggle1 Layer</nav>
      <nav className={`layer2 ${show2 ? "active" : ""}`}>toggle2 Layer</nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS and target the "inactive" classes like this:

```css
.inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, in your main file:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [show2, setShow2] = useState(false);

  const onToggleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
    setShow2(false);
  };

  const onToggleClick2 = () => {
    setShow(false);
    setShow2(!show2);
  };

  const resetToggle = () => {
    setShow(false);
    setShow2(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrap-navi">
      <div className="navi">
        <button onClick={onToggleClick}>toggle1</button>
        <button onClick={onToggleClick2}>toggle2</button>
      </div>
      <nav className={show ? "active" : "inactive"}>toggle1 Layer</nav>
      <nav className={show2 ? "active" : "inactive"}>toggle2 Layer</nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is a codesandbox with what I have described: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-cherry-o389b?file=/src/App.js:0-796